# wxPython, wxformBuilder and matplotlib: Resizing figure to panel

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxformbuilder

Hope you are able to help me with this.
- I'm new to both python and gui programming, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to create a simple GUI, using wxformBuilder, where the user can select a csv file and plot it in another panel (right_panel). 
The GUI and structure can be seen in the following image:
[GUI and Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH5iQ.png)

I'm able to plot some sample data in the panel using the code shown below, but i can not get the figure to scale to the panel when resizing the window.

```
import wx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
    FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas, \
    NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
import numpy as np
import gui2


class explorerFrame(gui2.mainFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent): 
         gui2.mainFrame.__init__(self,parent) 
         self.CreatePlot()     
         return

     def CreatePlot(self):
         self.figure = Figure()           
         self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
         self.axes.grid()
         x = np.arange(0, 6, .01)
         y = np.sin(x**2)*np.exp(-x)
         self.axes.plot(x, y) 
         self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.right_panel, -1, self.figure)

         return

 app = wx.App(False)
 frame = explorerFrame(None)
 frame.Show(True)
 app.MainLoop()
```

The following figures illustrates the scaling problem:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGEFq.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njz8q.png)

I have tried adding a boxSizer inside the panel, but i'm unsure of how to place the canvas inside the sizer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards 
Kasper

Answer (score 0):

Sizers can certainly do the job.
With wxGlade I have included some matplotlib examples.

This one should get you started on how to add a sizer to the panel: https://github.com/wxGlade/wxGlade/blob/master/examples/matplotlib/matplotlib_example.py